# numbers and words not numbers to words js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code gotten from the internet and it did not answer what I really wanted as output. I have two input fields; one for the input and another for the output and they are processed through this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AnEventHasOccurred() {
    var x = document.getElementById("onkeyup").value
    if (x >= "100") {
        document.getElementById("eventlog").value = "" +
        return x = ['Generalities'];
    }
}
</script>
```

What I'm really needing is that when I enter numbers below 100, output must be Generalities. I haven't got it correctly. And I went here to ask some help. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't even look like valid syntax -- you can't end a statement with `+`.

Comment: I've gotten it from here http://www.willmaster.com/library/tutorials/onkeydown-onkeyup-onclick-and-onchange-javascript-events.php and I modified something a lil bit assuming I would come up with 'Generalities' as output but my modification did not work. I need some help about this.

Comment: You copied the code, and took out everything after `+`. So why did you leave the `+`?

Comment: My bad. For clarification, before I put return x = ['Generalities']; it was just x. Then there was still an output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never outputting your value back into the output field. All you're doing is returning the value. You need to set the value of your output field to "Generalities".

**Example**

```
var input = document.getElementById("onkeyup").value;
// You should be giving your elements meaningful IDs.

if(+input < 100) {
    document.getElementById("output").value = 'Generalities';
    // Assumes an output field called "output".
}
```

Comment: +1 for being correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
function AnEventHasOccurred() {

        var x = document.getElementById("onkeyup").value;

        if (x < 100){
           document.getElementById("eventlog").value = "Generalities";   
         }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few errors.  Check this out for comparison:

```
function AnEventHasOccurred() {
    // should probably save the elements to variables 
    // since you'll be checking and changing the values
    var x = document.getElementById("onkeyup");
    var y = document.getElementById("eventlog");
    // should be 100, not "100"
    if (x.value < 100) {
        y.value = "Generalities";
    } else {
        y.value = "";
    }
}
```

This should work fine.  Check it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/NawWA/).

### More Recommendations

- Your `return` statement doesn't correspond with your "output": it
  does nothing valuable in this case.
- You check or set the value of an input by getting the element and
  using its `value` key.
- You should put semi-colons at the end of most javascript lines, with the exceptions generally being curly brackets `{}`, comments `// and /* */`, and empty lines.